# Why is the parentheses at end of return statement used in code below and why does if I don'y use parentheses it return address?

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement

EXAMPLE: Why dictuse1 return value but dictuse2 return address as specified below

```
def dictuse1(operator,x,y):
    return{
    'add':lambda:x + y,
    'sub':lambda:x - y,
    'mul':lambda:x * y,
    'div':lambda:x / y,
    }.get(operator,lambda:None)()
def dictuse2(operator,x,y):
    return{
    'add':lambda:x + y,
    'sub':lambda:x - y,
    'mul':lambda:x * y,
    'div':lambda:x / y,
    }.get(operator,lambda:None)     #No parentheses here compared to previous function
d = dictuse1('add',8,9)
print(d)      #return 17
a = dictuse2('a',5,4)
print(a)      #returns:<function dictuse.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f30d23f3ea0>
```

Comment: BTW,  it's not a good idea to use `operator` as a variable name because it's the name of a standard module. Incidentally, that module would be useful in this code because it defines the functions that you're defining with lambdas.

Comment: @PM2Ring I’m not sure `operator` would really help here, since the functions are all nullary closures over the `x` and `y` params, so you’d have to write something like `functools.partial(operator.add, x, y)`, which isn’t as much benefit as you usually get from the module. But still, definitely good advice in general.

Comment: @abarnert Ah, good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting such one-liners on some meaningful parts.

```
def dictuse1(operator, x, y):
    # Stores mapping from operator names (strings) 
    # to op implementations (functions == lambdas)
    optable = {
        'add': lambda: x + y,
        'sub': lambda: x - y,
        'mul': lambda: x * y,
        'div': lambda: x / y,
    }

    # Define a default op
    noop = lambda: None

    # Take the function by op name
    op = optable.get(operator, noop)

    # Exectute it and return a returning value of that function.
    return op()  # remove () and you have a dictuse2 here.
```

The only difference between `dictuse1` and `dictuse2` that the last one returns the function instead of the result of the invocation of that function.

Answer (score 4):

The parentheses have nothing to do with the `return`; they’re there to call a function, the same way you always call a function.

Let’s break this down into a more readable form:

```
function_table = {
    'add': lambda: x + y,
    'sub': lambda: x - y,
    'mul': lambda: x * y,
    'div': lambda: x / y,
}
```

So far, so good: this is just a dictionary that maps strings to functions, so you can look the functions up by name.

```
default_function = lambda: None
```

This is just a function that you can call and get back `None`.

```
function = function_table.get(operator, default_function)
```

This is just looking up a value in a dict. `d.get(key, default)` gives you `d[key]` if there is a value with that key, or `default` if there isn’t.

So, now `function` is that `add` function `lambda: x+y`, or the default `lambda: None`, or any of the other three , but whichever one it is, it’s a function that takes no parameters. So we can call It. This is where the parentheses come in:

```
value = function()
```

And now we just return that value:

```
return value
```

If you left the parentheses off, you wouldn’t be calling the function and returning the value it gives you, you’d just be returning it. So, instead of getting back `5` or `None`, you’d get back a function object. If you try to print that out, maybe it’ll say something like `<function '<lambda>' at 0x12345788>`, but it doesn’t really matter what it says; all it’s telling you is that the thing you’re printing is some function, and it has no name because you defined it with `lambda` instead of `def`.

Answer (score 1):

Because **in Python everything is an object**. This includes integers, floating-point numbers, strings, instances of other classes, *classes themselves* and *functions*.

The first function retrieves a function from the dictionary or uses the default value and *calls* it, returning the result of the call (a number in your case).

The second one returns *the function itself*.

The parentheses are notation for function call: `(lambda x, y: x + y)(1, 2)`, for example, calls the function and returns `1 + 2 == 3`. If you remove the parentheses, you'll get a function object.

Answer (score 0):

Because `get` method on dictionary return a default value if the key you are looking for is not in the dictionary, When you passed `a` which is not in the dictionary it returned `lambda:None` which is a anonymous function and to execute the function you have to call with paranthesis